# Migrating java application from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, ant, ivy, module-path, openjdk-11

Advance thanks, who are be going to help me.

***Story:*** till date my application is using `JDK8`, but right now I am migrating my application to `Open JDK11` and using `IVY` as dependency manager and `Ant` as a build tool.

***Problem:*** I was facing compile-time issues in eclipse for `javax`, but then I change `JRE` lib in the build path, from `classpath` to `Modulepath`. Now everything is working fine. But now the main problem is, while running `antbuild.xml` using `Ant`, this still giving me the same compile-time errors. I think I know what to do now, but how to do I don't know. I have to add `Open JDK11` as module path somewhere in `antbuild.xml`.

***Main Question:*** How to set `Open JDK11` as module path in `antbuild.xml` (BASICALLY ANT BUILD FILE).

if the question is still not understandable, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 11 months I am able to post the answer because I understand the actual problem and now I have a solution that I implement in my project and its working flawlessly, all the compile-time errors are fixed.

What solution I implement.

- Open project in eclipse, Eclipse latest version mine is 2019-06 build
- Right-click on project > `properties` > `Java build path`
- From `classpath` remove `Java 8` and above it, you will find `Modulepath`
- Click on `Modulepath` then `Add Library` from right button pane
- Now a dialog will open select `JRE System Library` press **Next** Button
- Now you can select **Installed JREs..** button to add the new version of `java`
- Press **Add** button from Installed JREs dialog
- Select `Standard VM` > press **Next** button.
- Now Select `JRE Home` from your filesystem make sure you select path up to bin, not bin
- Finish and apply all Changes
- Now Let eclipse build the project, of course, you will have errors.

---

***Reason for this problem***

See Java changes its file structure, so a lot of packages moved here and there. Some new packages are used, some got replaced and renamed.

So the basic problem is just this.

---

***Solution That We can implement to resolve compile-time errors***

- Open file which has errors, and sees which import is creating error, copies the file name which is not available, or not have error
- press `Ctrl` + `shift` + `t`, paste file name and see which possible options now we have, actually now we have more than one lib which is providing the same class implementation. so now we have to choose one and remove another dependency from the dependency manager.
- Now we have to add some more dependencies to support our code.
- Clean the redundant dependency.
- Now we just have to resolve the compile-time errors. that the solution we can do.

This solution helped me.
If you are facing the same issue, please connected me, I might help you with this.